# AWS how to enable bucket versioning on a specific folder of the bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way that we can enable bucket versioning on a **specific folder** of the bucket instead of the bucket level. I don't want to enable the bucket versioning for the whole bucket.

Can we use the Bucket Lifecycle to do that without enabling the bucket versioning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 bucket versioning is a bucket-level setting.

> Can we use the Bucket Lifecycle to do that without enabling the bucket
> versioning?

No, you cannot use bucket lifecycle settings to somehow enable the retention of multiple versions of an object, in a bucket that doesn't have S3 bucket versioning enabled.

Comment: Is there any alternative solution for that?

Comment: This could get complicated, but conceivably you could have a second bucket that did have versioning enabled and then sync uploads/deletes to the relevant objects in the primary bucket over to the secondary, versioned bucket. It might be viable if the upload frequency on each object was low (so there was minimal chance of synced versions arriving out of sequence). Probably a bad idea, but just thinking outside the box. Personally, I would go with two buckets - one for versioned objects, one for non-versioned objects. Versioning would be a 'class of service' type of thing for certain prefixes.

Comment: @fereshtehrabet use multiple buckets